# Howto configure barcode scanner HT-10 / Cino FuzzyScan F760-B to read long barcodes?

Tags: linux, usb, barcode-scanner

I have a USB barcode scanner that will not read "long" barcodes. The brand/model of this scanner is a bit unclear (at least to me). [This](http://honglitek.com/product2.html) is the scanner, but there is other information too:

**when plugged in**

```
usb 3-1.1: new full-speed USB device number 9 using xhci_hcd    
usb 3-1.1: New USB device found, idVendor=04b4, idProduct=0100    
New USB device strings: Mfr=1, Product=2, SerialNumber=0 Product: USB Virtual PS2 Port    
usb 3-1.1: Manufacturer: Future    
input: Future             USB Virtual PS2 Port     as /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1d.6/0000:06:00.0/0000:07:02.0/0000:3e:00.0/usb3/3-1/3-1.1/3-1.1:1.0/0003:04B4:0100.0008/input/input31    
hid-generic 0003:04B4:0100.0008: input,hidraw0: USB HID v1.00 Keyboard [Future             USB Virtual PS2 Port] on usb-0000:3e:00.0-1.1/input0
```

**lsusb**

```
Bus 003 Device 009: ID 04b4:0100 Cypress Semiconductor Corp. Cino FuzzyScan F760-B
```

I remember that some scanners need extra configuration to have them not to handle long barcodes as invalid but valid. I believe – not sure – that the codes that scanner fails to read are of `Code128`.

Anyone knows if possible to configure in Linux through USB / or perhaps scanning some configuration barcode?

*Google returns lots of sheets for other scanners which contain barcodes when read wil alter behavior of the scanner*

Comment: Why not buy one that does support what you need?

Comment: https://www.google.com/search?source=hp&ei=lMB6XPWWKKazjwTl74CgCg&q=HT-01+%2F+Cino+FuzzyScan+F760-B+to+read+&btnK=Google+Search&oq=HT-01+%2F+Cino+FuzzyScan+F760-B+to+read+&gs_l=psy-ab.3..33i299l3.1797.1797..5994...0.0..0.149.149.0j1......0....2j1..gws-wiz.....0.8o3kWgm9ea0

Answer (score 0):

You wrote: long barcode, that is different to long-range scanner.

I don't know how do you want to use the scanner, but maybe as a workaround, you can use a mobile-phone with some app for the transmission to your pc, till you get a new scanner.